# Should using SMO classification in WEKA take so long with large dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm, large-data, weka

I have a dataset of 205 features and 238000 samples. It is a combined dataset of several subjects' data that I want to use for between-subject classification.

I am using WEKA 3.8 with a 64-bit JVM and have chosen the SMO classifier with the default configuration (uses the PolyKernel kernel).

I am running on a Windows 7 64-bit PC with 8GB RAM and have already increased the memory settings for Java and WEKA to 6133MB, by following the information from here: 
http://www.heritagehealthprize.com/c/hhp/forums/t/646/using-weka-on-large-data-sets

However, so far when I start my classification test, it has been running for over 90 minutes with no sign of getting anywhere.

Can anyone advise me on how long a test like this should take, given my settings, please? 
Or is there a way I can speed up the process?

I have already subsampled the data in MATLAB and was hoping to not have to reduce the number of samples any further. Or will this be inevitable?

Answer (score 1):

Training time complexity of non-linear SVMs is between O(n<sup>2</sup>) and O(n<sup>3</sup>)

Weka SMO seems to be closer to the latter.

For instance, the execution time in ms for a random set with 205 features with Weka SMO looks like this:

[image]

It's hard to predict, but it could take anywhere from 1 day (n<sup>2</sup>) and 124 days (n<sup>3</sup>)

Depending on your use-case, you could use a linear kernel implementation, like LIBLINEAR.

Comment: Compact and concise answer. Scikit-learn allows to define the cache-size for the kernel-cache (time/memory-tradeoff). Maybe it's possible too in Weka to shift the complexity towards N^2.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Vowpal Wabbit for large datasets. It can consume very large datasets even on a laptop in no time. And it also supports kernels.

Vowpal Wabbit performs learning in online fashion - data points are streamed in one-by-one. You may want to shuffle your dataset before feeding it in.